# Django Error "django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“h” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']"

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I added a `DateTimeField` to one of my models but forgot to provide a default value in my models. When I ran the command `python manage.py makemigrations` it asked for a default value and I mistakenly gave  `'h'` as my default value, completely forgetting that it was a `datetime field`. Now I am getting this error. I deleted that line and also deleted the `dbsqlite3` file, but the problem still persists. What can I do now to get rid of this error?

Comment: In your app there should be a directory `migrations`, in which there should be various python files with names like `0001`, `0002`, etc. find the migration file which has that `h` as a default and delete it and all files after it in order.

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked, but since I deleted that `dlsqlite3` file, is there any way to retrieve that file back? :')

Comment: Can you get it back from the recycle bin, etc. Or do you use any version control (like git, etc.). If these options are not possible then no you cannot get them back. (at least easily, there might be _some_ chance if you try recovering deleted files using some recovery tools)

Comment: I got it in the recycle bin, thank you

Answer (score -2):

i have this error
but i change in class UserManager this code:

user = self.model(username, phone_number, full_name)

to

user = self.model(username=username, phone_number=phone_number, full_name=full_name)